# JSON parseerror when % is in data content

Tags: json, percentage, sign, parse-error

I need to fix problem on site, and i can't figure out how. I have function which dynamically download articles, but when it contain % sign it throws parseerror. Can anyone help me to change this function to work with % sign and explain me that JSON behavior?

```
$('.funfan_more').click(function(){
        if((offset*fun)+fun>=fun_count && (offset*fan)+fan>=fan_count){
            $('.load_more').html('').css('height','30px').css('background','none');
        }                       
        ajaxLoader.show();
        if(!loading) {
            loading = true; 

            $.ajax('<?php echo URL::site('load_posts'); ?>',{
              async: false,
                type: 'GET',
              data: {
                offset: offset
                },
              dataType: 'json',
              cache: false,
              error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                alert('Ups, some we have some' + textStatus + ' error here.');
              },
              success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                $('.ff_left').append(data.a);
                $('.ff_right').append(data.b);
                offset++;
                setTimeout(function(){  
                    Cufon.refresh();                    
                    loading = false;                                                    
                    ajaxLoader.hide();
                }, 1000);
              }
            }); 

        }           
        return false;           
    });
```

Comment: We'd have to see the JSON. But if you have JSON and you have a `%` that isn't in quotes, it's invalid JSON.

Comment: JSON contains html to display, and % are not in quotes, so how to fix it?

Comment: Use [valid JSON](http://json.org).

Comment: i validate that wrong json and -> "<br/><b>Warning</b>: sprintf(): Toofewargumentsin (...) online<b>107</b><br/>{", and it tells me nothing becouse its working well in anther cases.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Script wrongly preapared feed for site. It was a Kohana object pushed to string witch sprintf function, which was giving error if % was in website feed. Changing sprintf for normal casting to String type helped.